# Struggling with Itunes

Tags: itunes

I recently got a new laptop and just downloaded iTunes. I plugged in my iPhone, but none of my playlists that are on my phone appear on iTunes. Where are they?

Comment: did you synchronize ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it's not 2 way. You'll need to transfer the library over. Then, re-create the playlists, then re-synch.

I recommend using DeTune to transfer from Phone to iTunes.